# Unequal operators: != vs. <>, whats the difference?

Tags: operators

Whats the difference between `!=` and `<>` when applied on numbers?

Example:

```
a != b
a <> b
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is exactly no difference at all in functionality. Both are same. Actually <> is the elder brother of !=

<> was being used from `BASIC` language

!= started from `c`